# Reloading Tableview Cell after returning from Detail View Controller - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

Each cell in my tableView segues to a Detail View Controller where the user can favorite the entry. When the entry is favorited, a heart should show in the tableViewCell.

On re-launch of the app, the heart shows correctly in the favorited cells. However, it only shows after re-launch. I believe I need the reloadRows func, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works as intended.

**How can I make reloadRows dynamic so that the row that is reloaded is the selected indexPath?**

Basically as soon as the user favorites the entry, I want them to be able to go back to the tableView and see the heart in the cell.

As always any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the array of preferablly classes item so the edit is  reflected to original array , then after  editing it inside the detailVC then back inside the PrevVC either

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or use delegate/notificationCenter to reload the table , if you want to reload only the edited indexPath then create a var and hold it when **didSelectRowAt** is clicked and reload only that index inside the mentioned ways

```
var index:IndexPath? 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    index = indexPath
    // segue / push detail here 
}
```

With

```
if let ind = index {
  tableView.reloadRows(at: [ind], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: I only want to reload the edited indexPath and not the entire tableView. The reload needs to occur during the back segue.

Comment: not a problem read the entire answer hold the selected indexPath

Comment: I was just updating with code. Looks like I did very similar to what you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call the `reloadData` while you're in detail controller, you can pass the indexPath to that controller and replace tableView cell on the way back

Something like pass `indexPathForSelectedRow` to the detailViewController, update the dataSource there and call the `reloadRows` with that [passedIndexPAth]

Can tell more once you'll show the actual code.

Some pitfalls:

- mutating the dataSource if you do change it in the original controller can bring up some problems.
- any other simultaneous calls to the tableView/dataSource(mostly for the last one) have to be worked around properly. For instance if you're doing something else to them on `viewWillAppear`

The main idea is that you transfer the dataSource to the new controller and make it responsible for it every time you change the screen. Once you're done with the said viewController you go back and update the state. In case you need to resolve some simulatneous changes to the dataSource, you resolve them on the model level and pass the updates to your Views accordingly